# Anything similar to TMS or WMTS for WFS?

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs

I've been working with OpenLayers for a while, but problem got a question with WFS.

Not sure if it's supported by WFS, or OpenLayers, I want to achieve something like this, mostly for cache purpose:

As user pans/zooms the map, OpenLayers keeps sending out WFS requests with BBOX. I want to make coordinates in such requests keep only 3 decimal digits, in a sense, aligning to 0.001 degrees. Do I have to tinkle with OpenLayers, or is it built-in?

**EDIT**

I'm thinking about tiling for WFS, like TMS and WMTS do. Just we don't render image here, instead we "render" XML files.

Comment: Why would you like to do that? That could mean a lot of data which would slow your app performance.

Comment: Just a thought, I would like to use cache. Instead of doing queries every time a bbox comes in, I would like to chop them into predefined boxes, concatenating the bbox coordinates into strings, and index on it, or just store them to files.

Comment: You need something called UTFGrid. Have a look at these questions: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/utfgrid

Comment: Check this paper, especially the conclusion: http://www.ahahah.eu/data/doc/gisscience2012_gaffuri_draft.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there are efforts to tile WFS, but there are alternatives. Most vector tile implementations build upon GeoJSON chunks sent to the browser. A lot of information is linked on the [OpenStreetMap wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Vector_tiles).

A new development I find pretty interesting is [mapnik-vector-tile](https://github.com/mapbox/mapnik-vector-tile), built upon the incredible Mapnik map rendering engine. You find a handsome demo [over at MapBox](http://www.mapbox.com/blog/vector-tiles/).